# Docker compose problem , one application on all ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, module, port

I have done 3 simple rest applications
I run them with docker-compose
It seems that only a product app is on all 3 ports
I am fresh to docker.

here is Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
ADD credit/target/credit-ChocoladeIcecream.jar .
CMD java -jar credit-ChocoladeIcecream.jar

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
ADD client/target/client-ChocoladeIcecream.jar .
CMD java -jar client-ChocoladeIcecream.jar

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
ADD product/target/product-ChocoladeIcecream.jar .
CMD java -jar product-ChocoladeIcecream.jar
```

And the docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  credit_app:

    image: 'credit:latest'
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: credit
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - HOST_NAME=${HOST}
      - CLIENT_PORT=${PORT2}
      - PRODUCT_PORT=${PORT3}
    ports:
      - ${PORT1}:8080


  client_app:

    image: 'client:latest'
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: client
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - HOST_NAME=${HOST}
      - CREDIT_PORT=${PORT1}
      - PRODUCT_PORT=${PORT3}
    ports:
      - ${PORT2}:8080


  product_app:

    image: 'product:latest'
    build:
      context: ./
    container_name: product
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/${POSTGRES_DB}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
      - HOST_NAME=${HOST}
      - CLIENT_PORT=${PORT2}
      - CREDIT_PORT=${PORT1}
    ports:
      - ${PORT3}:8080

  db:

    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
```

here is also .env file if needed

```
HOST=localhost

PORT1=8089
PORT2=8090
PORT3=8091

POSTGRES_DB=database_name
POSTGRES_USER=user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass123
```

I check it with postman, trying to ad some elements, and when i GET all elements on each port I receive only Product

They must all run from one Jar, how can I make so each image is created from a different jar?

Please help me understand what went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in Dockerfile, you use `product` image in all three services. When you have several `FROM` statements, it won't build three images. This is used for multi-stage building, e.g. when you use one image (stage) to compile a binary and another one to just hold the product without compilers, kernel headers, etc.

One way you can solve this is to split the Dockerfile into three separate files (`credit.Dockerfile`,`client.Dockerfile`,`product.Dockerfile`) and then mention each one in their respective service:

```yaml
  credit_app:
    image: 'credit:latest'
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: credit.Dockerfile
    # repeat for other two with their Dockerfiles
```

Another way would be to use the same Dockerfile and different context but require you to drop `product-` (and others) prefix from the `jar` files. In other words, if they have the same name, you can use a Dockefile like this:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
ADD target/ChocoladeIcecream.jar .
CMD java -jar ChocoladeIcecream.jar
```

And to build different images from this Dockerfile you set different context:

```yaml
  credit_app:
    image: 'credit:latest'
    build:
      context: ./credit

      # By default it will look for the Dockerfile inside the root of context,
      # and you need to point to the file outside of it (relative to where
      # the docker-compose.yml is).
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
```

There is also a way to use `ARG` to create various images from one Dockerfile and it can be used in this case to `ADD` the correct jar file, but it won't work for `CMD`. So to make use of `ARG` you need that `jar` files inside container have the same name:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi
ARG APP
# Add file without prefix
ADD ${APP}/target/${APP}-ChocoladeIcecream.jar ChocoladeIcecream.jar
CMD java -jar ChocoladeIcecream.jar
```

And then you can set the `APP` argument in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
  credit_app:
    image: 'credit:latest'
    build:
      context: ./
      args:
        APP: credit
```